# Extract IFrame source using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a simple HTML/PHP web page and one IFrame in it. The IFrame contains links to external web sites.

I need some JavaScript that will extract the exact URL of the web page that is currently displayed inside the IFrame (not just the base URL of the external site). How can this be done?

Comment: Show us your HTML.  For security reasons, your iFrame must be on the same domain.  `iFrame.src` gets you the URL of an iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to get the contents of an iFrame. That page has an example too.

The following line will give you the **current** URL of the iFrame. Not the initial, but whatever it is showing when you call this:

```
 document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.location.href
```

Note: This will only work if the page is on the same domain.

Comment: remember to specify that this is a jquery function.

Answer (score 0):

The way to access the url on the iframe is by checking the src attribute.

```
console.log(iframe.src);
// will print http://example.com
```

However, when the user navigate to a different page in the iframe, the parent window will still show the original url on the src property